# C++ Base class/Derived class usage causing a crash?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am trying to understand how inheritance works in C++. I understand that when using pointers, the base class must use a virtual destructor, and I get the reasoning behind it.

Assume I have a parent class.

```
struct Parent {
  Parent() = default;
  virtual ~Parent() = default;

  // And a constructor with specific args
  explicit Parent(std::string name, int age, std::string favoriteColor) : name(std::move(name)), age(age), favoriteColor(std::move(favoriteColor)) {}

  std::string name;
  int age;
  std::string favoriteColor;
  std::string address;
  std::string city;
  std::string state;
};
```

And a child class.

```
struct Child : public Parent {
  using Parent::Parent;
};

// What's the difference between ^^^ version and this:

struct Child : public Parent {
  public:
    explicit Child(std::string name, int age, std::string favoriteColor) : Parent(name, age, favoriteColor) {}
};
```

I'm able to create instances of Child, but I'm sometimes getting a crash with this code running on an old Ubuntu machine. Is there anything off with how I use the child?

```
std::string name = "johnny";
int age = 37;
std::string color = "red";

Child c{name, age, color}; // This is safe?
Parent &d = c; // Is this safe?
```

Comment: In which version of the two do you get the crash? And why do you have the ctor parameters named the same as data members?

Comment: Would naming the ctor params same as data members cause a problem? I get the crash in the first version where I have `using Parent::Parent;`

Comment: I suggested about naming as naming them differently makes the code more clear. Now that you've said that you get the crash in first version, the question is much more clear.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and include the details of the crash, is an exception thrown? Is a signal raised? Have you tried using a debugger? Which compiler and compiler version are you using?

Comment: @Beebunny The code looks safe after considering what is happening here. Can you give an MRE?